# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException Error while copying content to a stream on first call only

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm calling ASP.Net web api that is running locally and ran into issue that occurs only after start of my app - only first call fails on System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException. I'm using windows authentications.
The first call never reaches my api and the exception is thrown on client. when calling PostAsync. Any subsequent call after the first one works alright.

StackTrace:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.StartRead()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult(

Code:

```
        {
            var exampleString = "example json as string";
            var content = new StringContent(exampleString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5099/api/test", content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // exception caught here on first call
        }
```

Api method called above

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = nameof(Permissions.MyPermission))]
        public ActionResult Post([FromBody]string payload)
        {      
        }
```

I am not sure what is happening here. My exampleString is valid JSON string, which is working on any subsequent call. this is only place in my app where HttpClient is used. what is causing - "Error while copying content to a stream"?

I'm targeting .Net Framework 4.5 on client.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `await` it like `await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5099/api/test", content)`

Comment: agree, the call can be awaited. But it changes nothing on the problem I'm describing in the question. thank you

Comment: Could you provide called api method  ? Attributes return result and e.t.c.

Comment: If you check your web server logs, do you see a 401 response for the first request?

Comment: It seems the first call of your request receives unauthorized response due to   Authorize attribute

Comment: @spodger I'm havin problems accessing server logs. Using only Http.sys without IIS. The only log i was able to get was httperr.log in \System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR. its looks empty(740kb but empty once opened)

Comment: and there was nothing in my asp.net logs. I'll check tonight what my logging level is. im afk till then. I agree that authorization is most likely cause of this. thank you!

Comment: alright, so there is nothing in httperr log, nothing in my web api log. is there any other place to look ?